# I'm getting the type error on writing the following code

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, typeerror

Code on Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("E:Datascience\Bivariate\Titanic.csv")

data.head()

data.shape


data['Survived'].value_counts()

data=pd.get_dummies(data)

data.fillna(0,inplace=True)

data.shape

train=data[0:699]


test=data[700:890]


x_train=train.drop('Survived',axis=1)

y_train = train['Survived']

x_test=test.drop('Survived',axis=1)



true_p=test['Survived']

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

logreg=LogisticRegression

logreg.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

Error:

```
Error - ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-cdb43f357e36> in <module>
----> 1 logreg.fit(x_train,y_train)

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: Changing `logreg=LogisticRegression` to `logreg=LogisticRegression()`, solves it?

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
logreg=LogisticRegression()
```

instead of

```
 logreg=LogisticRegression
```

This will solve your issue.

You can refer this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/logistic-regression-using-python-sklearn-numpy-mnist-handwriting-recognition-matplotlib-a6b31e2b166a)